# dpkg --configure -a makes ubuntu crash

Tags: apt, dpkg

Like several people on askubuntu, I'm facing some problems when using `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
I was trying to install a packet with `apt-get install` when terminal told me:

`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

When I use this command, the last info I can read are:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img.3.19.0-25-generic
```

When I use `uname -r` to print the kernel used in my system, I can read:
`3.19.0-58-generic`

I've been reading many thread around this problem, but rather none gave me a hint of what I should do. Does someone met the same problem?

Comment: There is no problem. You seem to have received an update of the kernel or grub which triggers the `update-grub` script that searches for bootable kernels and operating systems on your disk and reconfigures the GRUB boot menu. You just have a few old kernels installed, that's why the list is so long. They don't do any harm though. Absolutely nothing to worry about here.

Comment: eh... he does (did) have a problem... he was crashing. Otherwise, you're correct, its just update-grub adding found kernels to the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What were you trying to install?

It seems to be failing when updating GRUB.

Try booting to a previous kernel, like -56 (from GRUB), and see if you can run "sudo update-grub", without the quotes, in the terminal. If that works, try rebooting to the default kernel -58 or -59.

Comment: I'm trying to install Soundconverter (to convert tracks from .FLAC to other extensions), but it looks like dpkg is interrupted whenever I use `apt-get install`. 

Booting with the kernel -56, the sudo update-grub gives me once again the list of linux and initrd images (the same as before), plus these messages: `Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration done`.

Comment: I had to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` after trying to install my packet and this time it didn't crash my machine. After reboot on -59, I run the sudo apt-get install and it works. Terminal is even suggesting me the following:

Comment: `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-42 linux-headers-3.19.0-42-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-42-generic
  linux-signed-image-3.19.0-42-generic python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.`.    I guess I should use the autoremove command, what do you think ?

Comment: Good, it sounds like you're working again. The "Windows Boot Manager" message is just telling you that it found a Windows partition for your GRUB menu. The AUTOREMOVE is not necessary right now. Please rate/accept my answer.